# magento 2.3.4 problem add new product

Tags: magento2.3

i have problem with magento Version 2.3.4

my problem if i want add products i cant i get this error Although it was working normally before

I deleted all the add-ons that I had installed in order to check the matter again, but they also did not work

[image]

```
{"0":"Class Webkul\\Walletsystem\\Model\\Config\\Source\\ProductattrOptions does not exist","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/ObjectManager\/Definition\/Runtime.php:54]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime->getParameters() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Compiled.php:100]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Validator\/UniversalFactory.php:36]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\Validator\\UniversalFactory->create() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Eav\/Model\/Entity\/Attribute\/AbstractAttribute.php:642]\n#6 Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\AbstractAttribute->getSource() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Eav\/Attribute\/Interceptor.php:1181]\n#7 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Eav\\Attribute\\Interceptor->getSource() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php:697]\n#8 Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->setupAttributeMeta() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php:408]\n#9 Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->getContainerChildren() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php:381]\n#10 Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->addContainerChildren() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php:356]\n#11 Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->getAttributesMeta() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Eav.php:316]\n#12 Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Eav->modifyMeta() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/ProductDataProvider.php:73]\n#13 Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\ProductDataProvider->getMeta() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php:318]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php:218]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->create() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Generator\/UiComponent.php:140]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\UiComponent->generateComponent() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Generator\/UiComponent.php:103]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\UiComponent->process() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/GeneratorPool.php:81]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\GeneratorPool->process() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout.php:350]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->generateElements() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php:129]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Page\/Builder.php:55]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Page\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php:65]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->build() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout.php:257]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->build() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout.php:882]\n#24 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->getBlock() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/View\/Result\/Page.php:26]\n#25 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\View\\Result\\Page->setActiveMenu() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/NewAction.php:72]\n#26 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction->execute() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/NewAction\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#27 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->execute() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:108]\n#28 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/App\/AbstractAction.php:231]\n#29 Magento\\Backend\\App\\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#30 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#31 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [app\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php:143]\n#32 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#33 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#34 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/NewAction\/Interceptor.php:39]\n#35 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController.php:159]\n#36 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->processRequest() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController.php:99]\n#37 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#38 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#39 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#40 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#41 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http.php:116]\n#42 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#43 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]\n","url":"\/KeyGmxLLC_KeyG\/catalog\/product\/new\/set\/4\/type\/simple\/key\/26b9166143b18b9ea8012434f708401dc35c434e93adcbe3a4bc85faccd366cd\/","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"0c826eb87dd73874e812cf293dcab63060cd2bf8801d2af56e0c1ec84925b157"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the **"custom product attribute."**

You need to remove the **Webkul Walletsystem** extension custom attribute.

Comment: i don't have the module wallet system in attribute product i'm checking this

Comment: check-in "eav_attribute" table. you can find Webkul module path in "source_model" or "backend_model" column

Comment: i'm looking for all Ronak but no anything in eav_attribute with this name i'm try to install module again but i get this error if i want make command setup:di:compile i get this error Class Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\Source\CollectionFactory does not exist